# Why is my transition not working on class toggle?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to toggle position fixed to this bootstrap nav when scrolling down. I want the transition to be smooth. But the transition effect doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand">LOGO</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var header = document.getElementById("navbar");
    header.classList.toggle("fixednav", window.scrollY > 100);
});
```

```
.fixednav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    transition: top 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: This should not be the reason for this behavior, but you have an extra `</ul>` in your code, which should be a `</div>`. I submitted an edit on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an initial value so the transition property knows the beginning value to be transitioned to?

```
top: 0;
```

You could also try adding the transition property to the element itself instead of the toggle class.